# Sharepoint Online - Site permissions managed by end user

Tags: permissions, site, access

We are looking to build a basic Site template for our end users so we can easily create a Sharepoint Online site with very basic functionalities :
- one document library

By default the site has 3 groups of permissions:
- admin
- members
- visitors

The site will basically be like a network drive with just a folder hierarchy and documents.

We want to allow the site admin (end-user) to create groups and their access to the differents folders (ie: groupe A can access folder X & Y, and Groupe B can access folder Z)... Our Sharepoint consultants tells us that there is no easy way to do this and that a basic user wouldn't be able to manage this kind of admin with the current Ux... would this be accurate or would there be a simple way to allow them to administer this kind of access management? or are we condemned to use the complexe Sharepoint online user interface?

If I remember correctly, this kind of admin task on Sharepoint 2007 was really easy to do and very user friendly...

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Your consultant is an idiot and should be have their contract cancelled. They made this stupidly easy to in 2013/SPO.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to do. Just select a folder/library and hit the "share" button. Simple.

Though, check out Office 365 Groups, as they provide essentially a team site with pre-baked functionality. It may meet your needs better than a customized team site.

Comment: But this way existing users will be able to see the folders. He only wants group A or B to see some predetermined folders. Imo a better way would be to stop inheriting permissions and give unique permissions for the folders .

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, but if group a didn't already have access to the site or library, and if the folder was shared with them, they would then have access to just that library. If Group A will have access to the entire site but not certain folders, then yes, inheritance would have to be broken. Though, that would be a onetime only task, at which point the users would be able to just hit "share" and select whichever group they wanted.

Comment: Right. But here, i think he's already going to be creating a sharepoint group (admin/member/visitor) before giving permissions which automatically gives that group access to the site (unless he is not at least giving them read permissions which then would mean you are correct)

Comment: Hi folks, Thanks for the answers! I believe that breaking the inheritance; creating a specific group for that folder and manage access that way might be the way to go.  As I want the end-user to manage all this, we'll have to either do a very good user guide or create a page with specific shortcuts to simplify the task as much as possible...
Thanks again
Regards